# Copy standard output to file

Tags: bash, scripts

- Script1 uses `echo` (and other commands) to standard output.
- Script1 also runs other scripts, which also use `echo` (and other commands) to standard output.
- Script1 is called by a scheduler that stores the standard output from Script 1 as report.

Is there a way for Script1 to copy its own standard output to a file?

(A possibility would be for another script, say Script0, to run Script1 with output directed to a file and printing that file, or use `tee` to do both)

Comment: Just run your script1 like  `script1> outFile`

Comment: If you instead want `script1` to _always_ copy its output to a file (and not by specifying something on the command line), you would need to change each line to either use `>` or `tee`.

Comment: `>` will replace the contents in that output file. use `>>` if you want to copy   to the output file without replacing the content.

Comment: You probably won't need a wrapper script, just use `sh` directly: replace the call to the script with `sh -c '/path/to/script "$@" | tee log-file' _ arg1 arg2 ..`

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I knew I could run the script directing the output to file but what I wanted to know is if a script could direct its own output to file without running it from an outside script.

Comment: Assuming the script is bash, you can put `exec > >(tee logfile)`  at the start of the script. (note that it is `> >(...)`, not `>>(...)` nor `> > (...)`. Whitespace matters.)

Answer (score 0):

### An example as an answer

**Two scripts** in the same path

- `script1`

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  ./otherScript
  echo "script1" | tee script1.log
  ```
- `otherScript`

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  echo "otherScript"
  ```

**Lets start `script1` and check the output**

```
% ./script1       
otherScript
script1
```

and the logfile `script1.log`, created in `script1`

```
% cat script1.log 
script1
```